# How to focus on a particular row in agGrid(angular),If only the unique data in that particular row is only known?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an agGrid with some data having two rows as unique key:
    `id, name, address, status`
These are my columns where `name and status` is unique.
How can i focus on a particular row on page reload if i have a `name and status` known.

I tried to get the rowIndex for that particular row, But rowId for that row is not getting.

```
this.gridOptions.getRowNodeId = function(data) {
  return data.id
};
var rowNode = this.gridOptions.api.getRowNode('x');
rowNode.setSelected(true);
```

How i will get this data.id and x with only `name and status` value known ?

Please help me to find the solution.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: is your id column unique? or name + status combination?

Comment: Both id and name+status combination is unique..but i have only the value of name and status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, but since you dont know the id while retrieving the `rowNode` back, it will be useful to define a key with name+status since that is unique as well.

First of all, you need to provide `getRowNodeId()` to your grid.

Since name + status combination is unique, I am telling grid to use that as a key

```
gridOptions.getRowNodeId = function(data) {
    return data.name + '_' + data.status;
};
```

Now since you have known values of name and status, I would just do

```
var rowNode = this.gridOptions.api.getRowNode("name_status"); //pass your known name_status

rowNode.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: I want to only focus particular row without selecting it. Can we do it?